# Extension vs LocationPermission Class

Tags: swift

I have been working on my location-aware app. 
I am trying to extract location permission flow out of view controllers. so that I have cleaner code.

I wrote the LocationPermission class:

```
struct LocationPermission {
    private init() { }

    static func locationPermissionManager(with locationAuthStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus, viewController: UIViewController) {
        switch locationAuthStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            CLLocationManager().requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        case .denied, .restricted:
            Amplitude.instance()?.logEvent("Location Service: either denied or restricted")
            showLocationAceessDeniedAlert(on: viewController)
        case .authorizedAlways:
            Amplitude.instance()?.logEvent("Location Service: Authorized Always")
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            Amplitude.instance()?.logEvent("Location Service: Authorized when in use")
        }
    }

    static func showLocationAceessDeniedAlert(on viewController: UIViewController) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Permission update", message: "Location service needs to be enabled from settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let settingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .default) { alertAction in
            if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }

        alertController.addAction(settingAction)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        viewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Then I thought extension much cleaner and elegant. 
So I have also written Extension on `CLLocationManager`

```
extension CLLocationManager {

    static func locationPermissionManager(with locationAuthStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus, viewController: UIViewController? = nil) {
        switch locationAuthStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            CLLocationManager().requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        case .denied, .restricted:
            Amplitude.instance()?.logEvent("Location Service: either denied or restricted")
            if let viewController = viewController {
                self.init().showLocationAceessDeniedAlert(on: viewController, message: "Location service needs to be enabled from settings.")
            }
        case .authorizedAlways:
            Amplitude.instance()?.logEvent("Location Service: Authorized Always")
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            if let viewController = viewController {
                self.init().showLocationAceessDeniedAlert(on: viewController, message: "Location service: Please select 'Always' under location access")
            }
            Amplitude.instance()?.logEvent("Location Service: Authorized when in use")
        }
    }

    private func showLocationAceessDeniedAlert(on viewController: UIViewController, message: String) {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Permission update needed", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let settingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .default) { alertAction in
                if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
        }

        alertController.addAction(settingAction)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        viewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I both are function and working as intended. I am at this point confused which is a better solution.

I would like to ask wise people here. What solution is a better solution as per coding standards?

Answer (score 1):

An extension is useful if the code is widely related to the target class or struct.

Looking at the code it's apparently more related to `UIViewController` than to `CLLocationManager`.

How about that, the static methods have been changed to instance methods:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func locationPermissionManager(with locationAuthStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch locationAuthStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            CLLocationManager().requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        case .denied, .restricted:
            Amplitude.instance()?.logEvent("Location Service: either denied or restricted")
            showLocationAceessDeniedAlert()
        case .authorizedAlways:
            Amplitude.instance()?.logEvent("Location Service: Authorized Always")
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            Amplitude.instance()?.logEvent("Location Service: Authorized when in use")
        }
    }

    func showLocationAceessDeniedAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Permission update", message: "Location service needs to be enabled from settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let settingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .default) { alertAction in
            if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }

        alertController.addAction(settingAction)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion totally make sense. I would update it. so extension vs struct. extension is better option, is that so?

Comment: In this case, yes. But there is no common *best option*.